# Work with openstack security Groups - Denied outgoing SMTP

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-horizon

i am working in a openstack cloud as reseller an try to find out a solution to denied outgoing SMTP Connections for new instances.

I find out, I can add new security groups using the nova client. but how to create a rule for denied anything?

someone know this?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete the default egress security group rules in your `default` security group.

And another way is simply disconnect your local SMTP server connection so it won't send anything outgoing.

Comment: i solve it. create new SecGroup, delete default rules. allow TCP 1-24 and 25-65xxx

Comment: great! glad to hear that.